# Default test coverage tool in Intellij idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

does anyone know what test coverage tool does IntelliJ uses behind the scenes ? for my Scala project JaCaCo is not covering many Scala lines where are IntelliJ test coverage is covering most of the lines.

I need to upload the test coverage report to sonar so I need a report which has better test coverage percentage.

[image]

[image]

Thanks
Sri

Comment: Intellij uses its own?!

Comment: question is for asking Intellij guys to answer my question

Comment: can you please add more details to the issue. What is the code sample, where are the differences? Thanks

Comment: please create an issue at: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach the code sample to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am asking a question does Intellij has its own test coverage software ? or it usses scoverage behind the scenes when I choose Intellij as my test coverage in the IDE